# No puedo setear ruta en Laravel 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDA79.tmp'

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema al intentar guardar la ruta de la imagen que subo en la base de datos, la imagen si se almacena bien en la carpeta storage, y también sale bien en *Postman* cuando hago la consulta pero la URL en la base de datos no, lo que almacena es una ruta temporal como por ejemplo: `C:\xampp\tmp\phpDA79.tmp`

Mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tramite = Tramite::create($request->all());
    if($request->hasFile('img')){
        $destination_path = 'public/img';
        $imagen = $request->file('img');
        $img_name = $imagen->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('img')->storeAs($destination_path, $img_name);
        $tramite['img'] = $img_name;
    }
    return response()->json($tramite, 201);
}
```

---

Postman:
[image: POST desde Postman]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás insertando en BD todo el request tal cual llega, por eso estás insertando el nombre temporal que le dá PHP al archivo que llega en el request.

Luego manejas lo de la imagen, y aunque haces `$tramite['img'] = $img_name;`, no actualizas la BD con el nuevo valor.
Lo de postman es porque estás devolviendo el objeto después de haber cambiado el atributo `img`, pero eso no significa que ese valor persista en BD.

Te recomiendo que manejes primero lo de la imagen, y luego, antes de insertar en BD, cambies el valor del request con el nuevo valor que obtuviste al manejar lo de la imagen. Algo así:

```
$data = $request->all();
if($request->hasFile('img')){
    $destination_path = 'public/img';
    $imagen = $request->file('img');
    $img_name = $imagen->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $request->file('img')->storeAs($destination_path, $img_name);
    $data['img'] = $img_name;
}
$tramite = Tramite::create($data);
```

Comment: Puse como me dijiste pero sigue guardando el archivo temporal y ahora en postman ya no me muestra el url como antes, de todas formas la url al archivo temporal sigue igual

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ahora si me funciono!