# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar la ruta guardada en la carpeta uploads en la base de datos?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, storage, store

La imagen queda guardada en la carpeta `uploads/` en formato *jgp*, pero en la base de datos la ruta me aparece así:

```
C:\Users\alejo\AppData\Local\Temp\php877E.tmp
```

Y deberia aparecer, por ejemplo, asi:

```
uploads/vrskjshajsohenojs
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $datosCliente = request()->except('_token');
    Cliente::insert($datosCliente);

    if($request->hasFile('Foto')){
        $datosCliente['Foto']=$request->file('Foto')->store('uploads','public');
    }

    return Response()->Json($datosCliente);
}
```

Comment: Mueve `Cliente::insert($datosCliente);` después del `if` para insertar el dato correcto

Comment: Hola Alejandro Niño, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. No te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y así ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No puedo setear ruta en Laravel 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDA79.tmp'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405210/no-puedo-setear-ruta-en-laravel-c-xampp-tmp-phpda79-tmp)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS.